# updating entire row by adding values in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a column price for each product, now its already have the values, but i want to add +10$ to each product. Is there any way to update the entire row with addition.

I am not getting how to give the increment value here

```
update mytable set price=
```

Comment: You mean "update entire *column*" not *entire row*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. If your price field is numeric(int,float) type..

```
update mytable set price = price + 10
```

Answer (score 2):

Just an update to @a_horse_with_no_name's answer

`update mytable 
  set price = NVL(price,0) + 10;`

NULL + 10 is null (Atleast in oracle).

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following

```
update mytable 
    set price = price + 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  update mytable set price=price+10
```

Answer (score 0):

Can I join in?

```
UPDATE mytable SET price = price + 10;
```